# Web based stylus input?

Tags: android, asp.net, ios, windows

I currently have a medical application written in asp.net I built it with the hopes of it being cross platform. I was hoping to use styli and tablets to write input into sections in the app then saving that input as pdfs. I was thinking of using an html canvas and drawing on it. Does anybody have any experience with this or know any solutions that you think would suit me?

I was hoping to not have to build a native app with stylus functionality on each platform. I have looked into RealTimeStylus API but i believe that won't be cross platform. I also see that asp.net has a stylus class but I think that is also just windows! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.stylus.aspx

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks, John

Comment: As far as the stylus input part of it - I know that on Windows Developer Preview (The current non-public version of Windows 8), this is a non-issue, as the Operating System handles the Stylus input (and translates it into text).  It's one of the on-screen keyboard options (in addition to split and standard, there's an optiion that allows free-form text via the stylus).  You simply select the textbox and choose the keyboard, and select the one that allows free-form writing.  Some of my answers on this site recently have been submitted using the stylus to write free-form text on my test tablet.